# Spring MVC doesn't find views after changing port 8080 to 80

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, view, port-number

I have a tomcat8-spring project. The project works good in HTTP or HTTPS.

To get it working with HTTPS, I had to change in servers.xml the port from 8080 to 80. Now, HTML/JSP pages that were found before are now not being found, and Spring MVC throws 404.

My JSP's are now in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\views. I tried adding methods in the Controller that return the name of the JSP, but it didn't work. I tried Changing WEB-INF to WebContent and that also didn't work.

Where should my JSP's be? What address should I use to access them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it interest those who reads - You can tell tomcat to display webpages.
In your @RequestMapping in the controller, simply return the name and address of the HTML/JSP/JS/... page you want to display.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most general folder structure of the Maven Project if you are using it for Spring MVC.

[image: Folder Structure]

This is how you generally map to a view through a controller . Try doing the forward slash and see if anything changes. F12 Developer tool in your browser can be of great help for debugging

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/hello.htm")
public String handleIndexGet() {
    return "/pages/hello"; // forward to view hello.jsp
}

}
```